# Can a casual comparison of phenomena and assumptions based on it be presented in a journal/conference paper?

Tags: journals, conference, writing, writing-style

In comparison to the size of the universe, humans on earth are like bacteria on a speck of dirt. Much like in the animated movie "[Horton hears a who](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horton_Hears_a_Who!_(film))".

When writing a journal/conference paper, if one would like to present a fact:

> Universe being huge and Earth being negligible in comparison.

and compare it to similar phenomena and also present assumptions:

> There might be a civilization of creatures living on specks of dust
>   that we see everyday.

... is it considered acceptable to present such assumptions? Normally, scientific papers expect experiments and tabulated results, but can one present something purely philosophical as long as it seems logically sound (but there's no evidence to support it)? If yes, then what is the appropriate format to present the text? Can it be written as shown below?:

> **Observable Phenomenon:** The universe is 92 billion light years in diameter. In comparison, the Earth is a mere 12742km in diameter, and
>   the average human height is 1.7m and viruses can be just 20 nanometer
>   in diameter.
>   **Our hypothesis:** If the Earth could be assumed as a universe, it may very well be possible that there may be an entire civilization of
>   creatures living on atoms or electrons.

Would mentioning something like this make the reviewers reject the paper immediately or make them criticise it for being too casual or lacking in evidence? Or is a researcher allowed to philosophize such thoughts and present unproven theories/assumptions? If yes, then how should it be presented?

*ps: This is not for the field of humanities or pure philosophy. This is for a journal in the field of computer science. The question is not exactly about the universe and civilizations on specks of dust. The question is about how to present the author's assumptions that don't have proof.*

Comment: Your specific example, makes little sense, actually. "Civilization" has a meaning. But some things are just metaphors for other things. No one worries too much about that as long as you don't push the analogy too far. But for _civilization_ you would need some evidence.

Comment: Perhaps you could cite [**Two New Worlds. I. The Infra-World. II. The Supra-World**](https://archive.org/details/twonewworldsi00fouruoft/page/n10/mode/2up) by Edmund Edward Fournier d'Albe (1907) or [*He who shrank*](https://archive.org/details/Amazing_Stories_v10n11_1936-08/page/n13/mode/2up) by Henry Louis Hasse (1936). :)

Comment: It seems like what you are describing is closer to a blog post than a research article. Some journals will publish such musings when they are made by someone particularly influential, but these fit more in the category of editorial rather than scientific paper.

Comment: I think this question is about the content of your research.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro : Both the sources you've pointed to are absolutely fascinating!!! Thank you for sharing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In comparison to the size of the universe, humans on earth are like bacteria on a speck of dirt. Much like in the animated movie "Horton hears a who"... There might be a civilization of creatures living on specks of dust that we see everyday.

I think the example you have chosen here is obscuring your real question. It's not clear that this example makes any scientific sense, so if I saw this in a computer science paper I would find it very strange and probably suggest that the authors delete it. But your real question is about some hypothetical opinion, not about the (scientifically indefensible) suggestion that there are entire worlds on specks of dirt.

So, to the question I think you wanted to ask: it is OK to write casual comparisons if the comparison is useful and illustrative. Not all arguments have to proceed with a hypothesis test or linear regression or something. Your job is to convince the reader of your hypothesis; the argument for that can be heuristic, philosophical, or on a totally meta level. If it's a compelling point of view and the reviewers buy that it is plausible, they will likely be happy with your paper.

> **Observable Phenomenon:** The universe is 92 billion light years in diameter. In comparison, the Earth is a mere 12742km in diameter, and the average human height is 1.7m and viruses can be just 20 nanometer in diameter.
>
> **Our hypothesis:** If the Earth could be assumed as a universe, it may very well be possible that there may be an entire civilization of creatures living on atoms or electrons.

Assuming that the "Observable Phenomenon" and "Our hypothesis" are replaced by something less ridiculous, this seems entirely fine. You are starting with some quantitative observations, and asking the reader to draw a conclusion about some hypothetically possible scenario.